# How to put banner in recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, admob

I was able to put the banner in recylerview, but it is overlapping one of the items, it replaces one, instead of getting between them, does anyone know how to fix it?

I'm pulling an api, I do not know if that makes any difference. I searched for several tutorials, but I did not find it, what I need to do is add an admob native banner.

```
public class HistoricoAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>{

List<Capitulos> capitulos;
Context context;
private static final int DEFAULT_VIEW_TYPE = 0;
private static final int NATIVE_AD_VIEW_TYPE = 1;

public HistoricoAdapter(List<Capitulos> capitulos, Context context) {
    this.capitulos = capitulos;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (position>1 && position % 3 == 0) {
        return NATIVE_AD_VIEW_TYPE;
    }
    return DEFAULT_VIEW_TYPE;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    switch (viewType) {
        default:
            view = layoutInflater
                    .inflate(R.layout.row_historico, parent, false);
            return new MyViewHolder(view);
        case NATIVE_AD_VIEW_TYPE:
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.ad_unified, parent, false);
            return new NativeAdViewHolder(view);
    }
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (!(holder instanceof MyViewHolder)) {
        return;
    }
    MyViewHolder holder2 = (MyViewHolder) holder;

    Capitulos l = capitulos.get(position);

    int aInt = Integer.parseInt(l.getTempo());
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
    cal.setTimeInMillis(aInt * 1000L);
    String dataFormato = android.text.format.DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", cal).toString();

    SpannableString ultimoLido = new SpannableString("Último lido: " + l.getCapitulo());
    ultimoLido.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, "Último lido: ".length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

    SpannableString data = new SpannableString("Data: " + dataFormato);
    data.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, "Data: ".length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

    holder2.titulo.setText(l.getTitle());
    holder2.ultimoLido.setText(ultimoLido);
    holder2.data.setText(data);
    Picasso.get()
            .load("http://unionmangas.site/assets/uploads/mangas/" + l.getCapa())
            .into(holder2.capaView);

}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return capitulos.size();
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView titulo;
    TextView ultimoLido;
    TextView data;
    ImageView capaView;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        titulo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tituloHistoricoViewID);
        ultimoLido = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ultimosLidosViewID);
        data = itemView.findViewById(R.id.dataViewID);
        capaView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.capaHistoricoViewID);

    }

}

public class NativeAdViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public AdView mAdView;
    public NativeAdViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        mAdView = (AdView) view.findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                .build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Edited answer to ignore the banner click event

Issue is with `getItemCount`. As you are adding ads in between items you also need to increase the count as well. So that the number of items not get replaced with ad item.

```
public static final int ITEM_PER_AD = 3;
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    int itemCount = capitulos.size();
    itemCount += itemCount / ITEM_PER_AD ;
    return itemCount;
}
```

Accordingly you also need to exclude positions for ads, to get the original item position.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (!(holder instanceof MyViewHolder)) {
        return;
    }
    int itemPosition = position - position / ITEM_PER_AD ; // need to adjust to get the list item position excluding ads
}
```

Below code is about to ignore click event for the ads.

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
      if (position>1 && position % ITEM_PER_AD == 0) { 
            return; 
      }
      // rest of the code keep as it is.
}
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you.
One question, when I click on the item it sends the screen of an item. How can I solve this?

Comment: Sorry, did not understand what you want exactly **when I click on the item it sends the screen of an item**

Comment: When I click on the advertisement it is sending to the activity of the items. I want to stop this.

Comment: share that code where you handling click event.I think have already mentioned in edited answer. please check once

Comment: Your code is right. I tested it and it worked, but when I click on the banner, it opens one of the items.

Comment: This is the click event, it is in fragment: https://pastebin.com/DwdqLmq9

Comment: put this check on item click `if (position>1 && position % ITEM_PER_AD == 0) {
                   return;
                }`

Comment: It worked, thank you. Last question, can you tell me how I can add the banner in GridLayoutManager? In case I call 3 items per line and I want to put the horizontal banner below the items.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180286/discussion-between-krishna-sharma-and-oliverdamon).